# Noacl mount option has no effect. Trying to let all users write to ext4 on USB drive by default

Tags: permissions, mount, usb-drive, ext4, acl

When I click on a USB drive filesystem in Files to mount it, this mounts it to `/media/$USER/label`. This lets my user read/write to the drive if it's NTFS or FAT32, but fails to let my user read/write to EXT4 (this is a USB drive with an EXT4 partition on it). I've tried using `sudo mount -o remount,noacl /media/$USER/label`, but my user still cannot write to anywhere in the drive.

`touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied`

Is there a working way to mask ACLs on EXT4 mounts? Additionally, is there any way to do this by default for filesystems not listed in `fstab`? Ideally, my user would be able to plug in any USB drive and write to its filesystems, without compromising security on permanent system mounts.

If I remember correctly, it's possible to plug in the same USB drive to Windows (with Ext2Fsd) or MacOS (with ext4fuse) and start writing to it right away, as a normal user.

Comment: What do you mean by "ext4 distro installation"? Do you mean Live USB used for Ubuntu installation? Those are not formatted ext4. Please edit and update your question.

Comment: @user68186 Not a Live USB, but a full Ubuntu installation on an external USB device. I edited the question.

Comment: I have a similar USB full installation. I can't reproduce your problem.